# Scraping HTML table using selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to **scrape** each page HTML table using selenium web driver python by every time my code clicks the next page and **scrape** table but i am unable to do so because i don't understand how to click on these numbers every time using a python code.So i am sharing HTML code here

```
<div class="dataTables_paginate paging_full_numbers" id="orgSanitarias_paginate">
<a class="paginate_button first disabled" aria-controls="orgSanitarias" data-dt-idx="0" tabindex="0" id="orgSanitarias_first"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">First</font></font></a>
<a class="paginate_button previous disabled" aria-controls="orgSanitarias" data-dt-idx="1" tabindex="0" id="orgSanitarias_previous"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Previous</font></font></a>
<span>
<a class="paginate_button current" aria-controls="orgSanitarias" data-dt-idx="2" tabindex="0"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">one</font></font></a>
<a class="paginate_button " aria-controls="orgSanitarias" data-dt-idx="3" tabindex="0"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">two</font></font></a>
<a class="paginate_button " aria-controls="orgSanitarias" data-dt-idx="4" tabindex="0"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">3</font></font></a>
<a class="paginate_button " aria-controls="orgSanitarias" data-dt-idx="5" tabindex="0"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">4</font></font></a>
<a class="paginate_button " aria-controls="orgSanitarias" data-dt-idx="6" tabindex="0"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">5</font></font></a>
<span><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">…</font></font</span>
<a class="paginate_button " aria-controls="orgSanitarias" data-dt-idx="7" tabindex="0"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">38</font></font></a></span>
<a class="paginate_button next" aria-controls="orgSanitarias" data-dt-idx="8" tabindex="0" id="orgSanitarias_next"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Next</font></font></a>
<a class="paginate_button last" aria-controls="orgSanitarias" data-dt-idx="9" tabindex="0" id="orgSanitarias_last"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Last</font></font></a></div>`
```

[image]

I need idea about code that how can i **scrape** html table by clicking every time on the number to get that table of the page.Thanks..Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I am trying to iterate in following manner but it is not working...Can someone help?               
                                                                                                                                             
a=['1','2','3']
for i in a:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="orgSanitarias_paginate"]/span/a[i]').click()
    time.sleep(5)

Comment: I also tried using link text but it is not iterating the values